# Заполнение карты

Tags: java

Необходимо заполнить карту словом которое повторяется и частотой встречаемости

```
String[] str = "<массив слов>";
Map<String,Integer> rez = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
for(int i = 0;i<str.length;i++){
    boolean flag = false;   
        int count =1;           // счетчик равен 1 потому что одно слово уже пристутствует
for(int j=i+1; j<str.length;j++){
if(str[i].equals(str[j])){      //если слово повторяется  счетчик увеличивается на 1;
count++;
}
if(j==str.length-1){
flag=true              //Флаг используется для отметки того что цикл по j завершился
    }
    }
if(count>1&&flag==true){
    rez.put(str[i], count);
    }   
}
}
```

результат: разницы с ситуацией когда отсутствует проверка флага нет Необходимость проверки возникла для того 
чтобы отметить конец внутреннего цикла. 
{you=2, are=2, for=2, job=2, then=2, will=2, to=2, the=2, cover=2, letter=2, about=2, and=2, or=2, your=2, should=2, have=2, name,=2, You=2, which=2}

Comment: А в чем заключается вопрос?

Answer (score 5):

Воу. Посмотрите на ситуацию так: слово - это ключ. При итеративном проходе по массиву проверяйте, есть ли в карте такой ключ:

```
rez.containsKey(str);
```

Если нет - вставляйте со значением 1:

```
rez.put(str, 1);
```

Если есть - замените на единицу больше:

```
rez.put(str, get(str) + 1);
```

Вот два варианта решения:

```
String[] str = new String[]{"<массив слов>"};
Map<String, Integer> rez = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String item : str){
     if(rez.containsKey(item)){
         rez.put(item, get(item) + 1);
     } else {
         rez.put(item, 1);
     }
}
```

или так:

```
String[] str = new String[]{"<массив слов>"};
Map<String, Integer> rez = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String item : str){
    rez.put(item, get(item) == null? 1 : get(item) + 1);
}
```